# Balls and Bins: Calculate the Number of Combinations

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification

I have a unique Balls ($n$) and unique Bins ($k$) problem where $n\gt k$ and I wish to determine the total number of combinations where every Bin contains at least one Ball.  However, I have one additional constraint where there are an additional $\ell$ bins which the balls may fall into.

My approach is to assume that we can start with the full space of possible distributions and remove the combinations that fail to meet the criteria, so this would be $(k+\ell)^n$ total distributions of the $n$ balls among the $k+\ell$ bins.  The set of failures can begin with one among our $k$ bins empty, so this would be $(k+\ell-1)^n$.  Assuming this represents the pattern across the failed distributions, I would arrive at

$$(k+\ell)^n-\sum_{i=1}^k(k+\ell-i)^n$$

Is this a correct solution to this problem?

Comment: All the balls are considered different?

Comment: @cr001:  yes they are

Comment: I think you are missing $k\choose i$ in the summation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you have done this, you have a problem with double-counting. Namely, $(k+\ell-1)^n$ will include assignments where one box is empty, but also some arrangements where more than one box is empty. To do this correctly, you need to use the principle of inclusion-exclusion.

You take all $(k+\ell)^n$ placements of balls into bins, and for each of the $k$ bins, you subtract the $(k+\ell-1)^n$ placements where that bin is empty. However, this will double subtract the assignments where *two* bins are empty, so these need to be added back in. You then need to correct for the assignments with three empty bins, and so on. The result is
$$
\sum_{i=0}^k(-1)^i\binom{k}i(k+\ell-i)^n
$$

Comment: Thanks!  I knew I was missing something, but I couldn't figure out what it was...